# Memory of type "root-set" reallocation Error - Erlang

Tags: linux, erlang, solaris

I have been running a crypto-intensive application that was generating pseudo-random strings, with special structure and mathematical requirements. It has generated around 1.7 million voucher numbers per node in over the last 8 days. The generation process was CPU intensive, with very low memory requirements. 
Mnesia running on OTP-14B02 was the storage database and the generation was done within each virtual machine. I had 3 nodes in the cluster with all mnesia tables `disc_only_copies` type. Suddenly, as activity on the Solaris boxes increased (other users logged on remotely and were starting webservers, ftp sessions, and other tasks), my bash shell started reporting a
`fork: not enough space` error.

My erlang Vms also, went down with this error below:

```
Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
temp_alloc: Cannot reallocate 8388608 bytes of memory (of type "root_set").
```

Usually, we get memory allocation errors and not `memory re-location errors` and normally memory of type `"heap"` is the problem. This time, the memory type reported is type `"root-set"`.

Qn 1. What is this `"root-set"` memory?

Qn 2. Has it got to do with CPU intensive activities ? (why am asking this is that when i start the task, the Machine reponse to say mouse or Keyboard interrupts is too slow meaning either CPU is too busy or its some other problem i cannot explain for now)

Qn 3. Can such an error be avoided?  and how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fork: not enough space` message suggests this is a problem with the operating system setup, but:

#### Q1 - The Root Set

The Root Set is what the garbage collector uses as a starting point when it searches for data that is *live* in the heap. It usually starts off from the registers of the VM and off from the stack, if the stack has references to heap data that still needs to be live. There may be other roots in Erlang I am not aware of, but these are the basic stuff you start off from.

That it is a reallocation error of exactly 8 Megabyte space could mean one of two things. Either you don't have 8 Megabyte free in the heap, or that the heap is fragmented beyond recognition, so while there are 8 megabytes in it, there are no contiguous such space.

#### Q2 - CPU activity impact

The problem has nothing to do with the CPU per se. You are running out of memory. A large root set could indicate that you have some very deep recursions going on where you keep around a lot of pointers to data. You may be able to rewrite the code such that it is tail-calling and uses less memory while operating.

You should be more worried about the slow response times from the keyboard and mouse. That could indicate something is not right. Does a vmstat 1, a sysstat, a htop, a dstat or similar show anything odd while the process is running? You are also on the hunt to figure out if the kernel or the C libc is doing something odd here due to memory being constrained.

#### Q3 - How to fix

I don't know how to fix it without knowing more about what the application is doing. Since you have a crash dump, your first instinct should be to take the crash dump viewer and look at the dump. The goal is to find a process using a lot of memory, or one that has a deep stack. From there on, you can seek to limit the amount of memory that process is using. either by rewriting the code so it can give memory up earlier, by tuning the garbage collection setup for the process (see the spawn options in the erlang man pages for this), or by adding more memory to the system.